# Java Buttons not working as intended

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

the buttons only seem to multiply and not divide in my program. I do not know what is causing this, but any advice would be highly appreciated.

```
//View the buttom to be pushed
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MultDivide extends JFrame
{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
    private double value;
    private JButton multbutton;
    private JButton divbutton;
    private JLabel label;

    public MultDivide()
    {
        super("I Multiply and Divide");

        //get content pane and sets its layout
        Color background = new Color(100,100,0);
        Container contain = getContentPane();
        contain.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contain.setBackground(background);



        //create multiple button
        multbutton = new JButton("x5 ");
        contain.add(multbutton);

        //create divide button
        divbutton = new JButton("/5");
        contain.add(divbutton);

        //initialize the value to 50
        value = 50;

        // create a label to display value
        label = new JLabel("Value: " + Double.toString(value));
        contain.add(label);

        //creates listener and executes desired result
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        multbutton.addActionListener(listener);
        divbutton.addActionListener(listener);

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    privateclass ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //handle button event
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent mult)
        {
            //updates counter when the button is pushed
            if(divbutton.isSelected())
            {
                value = value / 5.0;
                label.setText("Value: " + Double.toString(value));
            }
            else
            {


                    value = value* 5.0;
                    label.setText("Value: " + Double.toString(value));

            }

        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're checking `isSelected()` and that only works with JToggleButtons and its children including JRadioButton and JCheckBox. Instead of this, get the ActionEvent's source and check which button was pushed. Call `getSource()` on the ActionEvent parameter to do this.

e.g.,

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent mult) {
        JButton sourceBtn = (JButton) mult.getSource();
        if(sourceBtn == divbutton) {
            value = value / 5.0;
            label.setText("Value: " + Double.toString(value));
        } else {
            value = value* 5.0;
            label.setText("Value: " + Double.toString(value));
        }
    }
}
```